# Android - Espresso - Assert object when other object is present in List

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso

I need to make an instrumented test using espresso or uiautomator (I'm open to other sugestions) to validate the existence of a value based on another value in a list.

The questions/anwsers I have seen, all have solutions regarding the using of an index from the list view, or using a specific tag with a number associated (which is basicaly the same thing)

My problem is that I don't know the position, but I need to check that when I encounter a specific String value, that on that row, an image is showing.

The list are populated by a Custom Adapter.

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After several attemps I end up doing some custom matcher that with a few alterations should work for all kind of views.

Here's how it's called in the test:

```
onView(CommonMatchers.withTextAndComparableText(R.id.tvTypeName, R.id.rlParentView, R.id.tvName, is(typeNameText), is (nameText))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

variables:
`childId` - view that I  want to compare from,
`parentId` - parent of both views,
`comparableChildId` - view that I want to compare to

Here's the `Matcher`:

```
public static Matcher<View> withTextAndComparableText(int childId, int parentId, int comparableChildId,
        final Matcher<String>
                eventMatcher,
        final Matcher<String> parcelIdMatcher) {
    checkNotNull(eventMatcher);
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with text: ");
            eventMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
            if (eventMatcher.matches(textView.getText().toString()) && childId == textView.getId()) {
                TextView textViewToCompare = (TextView) checkParentAndComparableChildForValidation(parentId,
                        comparableChildId, textView, parcelIdMatcher);
                return textViewToCompare != null && parcelIdMatcher.matches(textViewToCompare.getText().toString());
            }
            return false;
        }

    };
}
```

Then add the next private methods to first get the parent view and then the comprable child view

```
    private static View checkParentAndComparableChildForValidation(int parentId, int comparableChildId,
        View objectView,
        Matcher<String> parcelIdMatcher) {
    ViewParent parentView = findParentRecursively(objectView, parentId);
    Object childObject = getObjectFromParent((View) parentView, comparableChildId);

    if (childObject instanceof View) {
        return (View) childObject;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Object getObjectFromParent(View viewParent, int childId) {
    return viewParent.findViewById(childId);
}

private static ViewParent findParentRecursively(View view, int targetId) {
    if (view.getId() == targetId) {
        return (ViewParent) view;
    }
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return findParentRecursively(parent, targetId);
}
```

And voilá!

If you want to compare with an Image or other view, there's few alterations to be done...

```
    public static Matcher<View> withImageAndComparableText(int childId, int parentId, int comparableChildId,
        final Matcher<String> parcelIdMatcher) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, ImageView>(ImageView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with id: " + childId);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(ImageView imageView) {
            if (imageView.getId() == childId) {
                TextView textViewToCompare = (TextView) checkParentAndComparableChildForValidation(parentId,
                        comparableChildId, imageView, parcelIdMatcher);
                return textViewToCompare != null && parcelIdMatcher.matches(textViewToCompare.getText().toString());
            }

            return false;
        }

    };
}
```

and the call in the tests:

```
        onView(CommonMatchers.withImageAndComparableText(imageId, R.id.rlParentView, R.id.name, is(parcelId)))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Hope it helps